# Grouping methods of a Python class

Tags: python, object-oriented

I have a class with numerous methods, and so I would like to split these up into groups. This would make it easier for the user to find the method they are after. Here is a minimal example of this functionality.

```
class Greeter():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.spanish = Spanish(self)

   def generic(self):
       return f"Hello, {self.name}"

class Spanish():

        def __init__(self, greeter):
            self.grtr = greeter

        def hola(self):
            return f"Hola, {self.grtr.name}"

        def buen_dia(self):
            return f"Buenos días, {self.grtr.name}"

greeter = Greeter("Ann Example")
greeter.generic()
#> "Hello, Ann Example"
greeter.spanish.hola()
#> "Hola, Ann Example"
```

This feels like a hacky approach. Are there places people could see this failing? Is there a better solution in general?

**EDIT**

As suggested, here is a reduced example of my actual need for this functionality:

```
class Matrix():

    def __init__(self, m, n, data):
        # checks on m, n, data
        self.m = m
        self.n = n
        self.data = data
        self.decomposition = Decomposition(self)

    # many generic methods some returning more matrices
    def __add__(self, other):
        # add matrices
        return Matrix(m, n, data)

    # some methods will affect m, n, data
    def transpose(self):
        # set up new attributes
        self.m = m
        self.n = n
        self.data = data

class Decomposition():

    def __init__(self, mtrx):
        self.mtrx = mtrx

    # NB: eventually these might change m, n, data
    def QR(self):
        # do stuff for QR decomposition using self.mtrx
        return Q, R

    def LU(self):
        # do stuff for LU decomposition using self.mtrx
        return L, U
```

Comment: Why don't you make the Generic class abstract and then have Spanish or whatever language inherit from it? That way you can have generic methods for each message you want to display, and override them in the child classes

Comment: I appreciate that with this abstract example that makes sense but for my actual use case (which is probably just confusing to share) it doesn't quite work as there would be multiple groups of methods which all need to be accessed. It's just a way of grouping methods. If I want to greet someone in Spanish I don't have to search through all the methods for other languages but rather specify that I'm after a Spanish greeting first then choose the method. It would be clunky to have to instantiate a new class member to do this.

Comment: In your `reduced example`, I do not see `a class with numerous methods`. (I do see a funny `transpose()`.) Please present [enough actual code from your project to support meaningful reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If need be, *someone* is bound to try and sort out *why* the presented is confusing.

Comment: @greybeard This feels like obsessive nit-picking and it's a very unfriendly welcome to this community. I'm sure you can imagine what multiple methods look like. I've explained all the types of methods I have and what they might return which is what is important. For all it matters, the others could be `transpose1()`, `transpose2()`, ... `transpose1000()` and any answer would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is a review of the initial code that was posted. Unfortunately, I don't have time to revise it now for the new code.

---

Wanting to lessen the number of methods in a class is on its own a poor reason to split up a class into multiple. Classes can have many methods, and we can use IDE functionality and good documentation to make sense of a class.

Having many methods *can* suggest though that the class is doing too much, and *that* would be a more logical justification to split the class up. A better thing to think about is not the size of the class, but what the job of the class is, and if it's doing too many things.

That said, if you feel like it's justified to split it, I wouldn't do it as you have here. You've given the entire state of the `Greeter` object to `Spanish`. If `Spanish` begins using a lot of the state in `Greeter`, you now have two tightly coupled classes that will begin to break as you make changes to either.

Just give `Spanish` the information that it explicitly needs:

```
class Spanish:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def hola(self):
        return f"Hola, {self.name}"

    def buen_dia(self):
        return f"Buenos días, {self.name}"
```

And

```
class Greeter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.spanish = Spanish(name)  # And just pass the name
    . . .
```

This setup really doesn't make sense though. To get a greeting in Spanish, you need to access an object that greets in English? Even combined it doesn't make much sense. Having an object that greets in multiple languages seems odd. It would make more sense to have completely discrete classes that don't know about each other.

With a toy example like this though, it's really hard to make a concrete suggestion because the actual intent isn't clear. The textbox that I'm writing the answer in is also bugging out, so I'm going to submit this before I lose everything.

Comment: But in this case how do I keep Greeter and Spanish in sync? Say, I add an `update_name()` method? I seems excessive and confusing to have my code track down all method groups and update the name there.

Also, I appreciate the difficulty of working with these abstract examples. I feel confident that this is a reasonable thing to do for my project though. It's inspired by Pandas' Series.str.replace() and the likes though the source code for that is too complex for me to disect and base my solution on.

Comment: @TimHargreaves If you needed the objects to be in sync, then that changes things a bit. You didn't post very detailed requirements, and intent wasn't super clear from the example code though, so it isn't entirely clear what the end goal is. I'll note, that's one reason why toy code like this is discouraged here.

Comment: Apologies. I've had people discourage the use of complex examples rather than simple, abstract ones too. I will edit my question to add my full use case.

Comment: @TimHargreaves Ideally, the code should be a complete, runnable example (or close to it) if the whole thing is too complex to post in its entirety. It needs to be real enough that the intent is clear, but also a reasonable enough example that reviewers will be able to make sense of it. Some people post massive projects here, and it's hard to expect people to understand the code enough in its entirety to be able to make suggestions.

Comment: Apologies. I've fixed my question to make my use case clearer.

Comment: _I don't have time to revise it now for the new code._ - The OP editing their code so much that it invalidates your answer is against site policy.

Comment: @Reinderien The code I'm addressing remains. My answer isn't necessarily invalidated by the addition of new code. I'll admit though, this wasn't an ideal question.

Answer (score 1):

Circular references are bad; if you split the classes into multiple files (which you'll probably want to do if the goal is to make navigation easier) then circular references usually mean circular imports, which cause other problems.

If you need to split a class up, splitting it into superclasses/mixins is better IMO.  For example:

```
class MatrixBase:
    """Matrix base class.
    Defines instance variables and initialization."""
    def __init__(self, m, n, data):
        # checks on m, n, data
        self.m = m
        self.n = n
        self.data = data


class MatrixGenericOps(MatrixBase):
    """Generic matrix operations."""

    # many generic methods some returning more matrices
    def __add__(self, other):
        # add matrices
        return type(self)(self.m, self.n, self.data)

    # some methods will affect m, n, data
    def transpose(self):
        # set up new attributes
        self.m = m
        self.n = n
        self.data = data


class MatrixDecomposition(MatrixBase):
    """Decomposition operations."""

    # NB: eventually these might change m, n, data
    def QR(self):
        # do stuff for QR decomposition using self.mtrx
        # return Q, R
        pass

    def LU(self):
        # do stuff for LU decomposition using self.mtrx
        # return L, U
        pass


class Matrix(MatrixGenericOps, MatrixDecomposition):
    """A fully-functional Matrix."""
    pass
```

Comment: This seems like a good structure. Thank you. Is there a way I can make this compatible with the naming convention `Matrix.decomposition.QR()`? The idea is that a user is unlikely to remember the name of every decomposition but would be reminded when they saw all options from a shorter list.

Comment: I would do this just by naming them `decompose_qr` and `decompose_lu` or whatever so that the naming pattern is easy to remember and makes decomposition functions easy to discover.  Having the functionality live on a separate object is weird if it's still something you're doing to the matrix itself IMO, but I'm a big fan of naming things such that they're easily searchable.